# Create Custom Model for Permission and Roles in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to create Custom Permissions and Role Tables so that i can list/update user's permissions and roles from the front end using DRF. **I don't want to use Django Admin panel** to do that. I have Created the models as seen in the below image. Now how do i use them for authentication

[image: Reference Image]

Answer (score 0):

For authentication:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/

For the permission you will have to create your own decorator and template tag to check them.

But I don;t understand why you want to do that. If you can edit these models, why not just keep the Django's ones and edit them?

Comment: i am creating a Dashboard (in Angular) where the admin users can edit/update normal user's permission as per requirement and for that purpose i need to write GET and PATCH methods for Permissions

Comment: And again I don't understand why you can not do that with the normal permission system

Comment: How do i list all the permissions on the frontend side and update them for particular users?

Comment: Also the project is based on Microservices Architecture where all the module run individually on different ports. i want to provide custom permissions to user for each module. 

This is the USER Module, where the authorization and the authentication takes place.